# Requirejs Jquery prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, requirejs

I am trying to import jquery into my prototyped class which works initially in the constructor.

I lose my scope of jquery in the call to resizeCanvas event. It says the width() and height() function is undefined.

Is there a way I won't lose the jquery variable.

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    function Canvas() {
        this.canvas   = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.context  = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.rowbuild = $('#rowbuild');
    }

    Canvas.prototype.addResizeListener = function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas, false);
    };
    Canvas.prototype.resizeCanvas = function() {
        this.canvas.width  = this.rowbuild.width();
        this.canvas.height = this.rowbuild.height();
    };

    return Canvas;
});
```

Comment: I found the problem I need to pass the context of jquery. $(window).on('resize', this.resizeCanvas);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the listener to the correct context object using `bind` or `$.proxy`.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas.bind(this), false);
```

Besides, why are you using `addEventListener` if you are already using jQuery?